# feed empty pandas.dataframe with several files

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

I would like to feed a empty `dataframe` appending several files of the same type and structure. However, I can't see what's wrong here:

```
def files2df(colnames, ext):
    df = DataFrame(columns = colnames)
    for inf in sorted(glob.glob(ext)):
        dfin = read_csv(inf, sep='\t', skiprows=1)
        print(dfin.head(), '\n')
        df.append(dfin, ignore_index=True)
    return df
```

The resulting dataframe is empty. Could someone give me a hand?

```
    1.0  16.59  0.597  0.87  1.0.1   3282 100.08
 0  0.953  14.52  0.561  0.80   0.99   4355      -
 1  1.000  31.59  1.000  0.94   1.00   6322      -
 2  1.000   6.09  0.237  0.71   1.00  10568      -
 3  1.000  31.29  1.000  0.94   1.00  14363      -
 4  1.000  31.59  1.000  0.94   1.00  19797      - 

      1.0   6.69  0.199  0.74  1.0.1   186 13.16
 0      1   0.88  0.020  0.13   0.99   394     -
 1      1   0.75  0.017  0.11   0.99  1052     -
 2      1   3.34  0.097  0.57   1.00  1178     -
 3      1   1.50  0.035  0.26   1.00  1211     -
 4      1  20.59  0.940  0.88   1.00  1583     - 

      1.0  0.12  0.0030  0.04  0.97   2285 2.62
 0     1  1.25   0.135  0.18  0.99   2480    -
 1     1  0.03   0.001  0.04  0.97   7440    -
 2     1  0.12   0.003  0.04  0.97   8199    -
 3     1  1.10   0.092  0.16  0.99  11174    -
 4     1  0.27   0.007  0.06  0.98  11310    - 

   0.244  0.07  0.0030  0.02  0.76  41314 1.32
 0  0.181  0.64   0.028  0.03  0.36  41755    -
 1  0.161  0.18   0.008  0.01  0.45  42420    -
 2  0.161  0.18   0.008  0.01  0.45  42461    -
 3  0.237  0.25   0.011  0.02  0.56  43060    -
 4  0.267  1.03   0.047  0.07  0.46  43321    - 

 0.163  0.12  0.0060  0.01   0.5  103384 1.27
 0  0.243  0.27   0.014  0.02  0.56  104693    -
 1  0.215  0.66   0.029  0.04  0.41  105192    -
 2  0.190  0.10   0.005  0.01  0.59  105758    -
 3  0.161  0.12   0.006  0.01  0.50  109783    -
 4  0.144  0.16   0.007  0.01  0.42  110067    - 

Empty DataFrame
Columns: array([D, LOD, r2, CIlow, CIhi, Dist, T-int], dtype=object)
Index: array([], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

df.append(dfin, ignore_index=True) returns a new DataFrame, it does not change df in place.
Use df = df.append(dfin, ignore_index=True). But even with this change i think this will not give what you need. Append extends a frame on axis=1 (columns), but i believe you want to combine the data on axis=0 (rows)

In this scenario (reading multiple files and use all data to create a single DataFrame), i would use pandas.concat(). The code below will give you a frame with columns named by colnames, and the rows are formed by the data in the csv files.

```
def files2df(colnames, ext):
    files = sorted(glob.glob(ext))
    frames = [read_csv(inf, sep='\t', skiprows=1, names=colnames) for inf in files]
    return concat(frames, ignore_index=True)
```

I did not try this code, just wrote it here, maybe you need tweak it to get it running, but the idea is clear (i hope).

Comment: thank you very much for helping. I do want extend columns on axis=0.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I found another solution, but don't know which one is faster.

```
def files2df(colnames, ext):
    dflist = [ ]
    for inf in sorted(glob.glob(ext)):
        dflist.append(read_csv(inf, names = colnames, sep='\t', skiprows=1))
        #print(dflist)                                                                                                                            
    df = concat(dflist, axis = 0, ignore_index=True)
    #print(df.to_string())                                                                                                                        
    return df
```

Comment: This is from pandas point of view the same as what i did. The difference is that i used list comprehension (http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to create the list of frames.

Comment: @Wouter Overmeire: Thank you very much for the link. One more question: suppose I have files with no headers (like in my first post above), is there any way to makke pandas automatically index columns? in other words, why do I always have to set column names when read_csv?

Comment: You can skip names=colnames and set header=None, this way default column names will be used: read_csv(inf, sep='\t', skiprows=1, header=None) (i`m on master)